# Error [TOKEN_MISSING]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making/reprogramming the **Node** bot for Discord and when I have everything ready to start I put `node .` and I get the title error.

```js
Error [TOKEN_MISSING]: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.
    at Function.fetchRecommendedShards (C:\Users\diplo\Desktop\Node-Discord-Bot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:285:23)
    at ShardingManager.spawn (C:\Users\diplo\Desktop\Node-Discord-Bot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\sharding\ShardingManager.js:186:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\diplo\Desktop\Node-Discord-Bot-master\index.js:38:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'TOKEN_MISSING'
}
```

Comment: That means that when you logged in the client, you didn't provide a token or the token you tried to provide was undefined. You're gonna need to edit your post with the code you're using if you want help in debugging

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a guide to set up your discord bot? If no, I suggest poking around Discord's official guide: https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#creating-configuration-files (this section deals with how you handle your token). Are you putting your token in the config.json file, or are you putting it in an .env file? How are you calling the token?

I would also run `node index.js` first (or whatever the name of your base file of the bot code is, instead of index.js), and only after that using  `node .`